# Call recordings in Asterisk using MixMonitor

Tags: asterisk, telephony, freeswitch, pbx, asteriskami

I'm just starting out with Asterisk and following the [O'Reilly Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025894.do) to set up a test Asterisk server. I have set up a VM with CentOS 6.4, which has 1GB RAM and 50 GB HDD.

After installation, I set up soft phones successfully on 2 PCs which were able to call each other. I have to record these calls now - on searching, I found [this site](http://www.pbxer.com/recording-phone-calls/) and ediiting my `extensions.conf` accordingly.

Here's my `extensions.conf`

```
[globals]

EXT_TESTTWO=SIP/0000FFFF0002
EXT_TESTONE=SIP/0000FFFF0001

[default]
exten => 0000FFFF0001,hint,SIP/0000FFFF0001
exten => 0000FFFF0002,hint,SIP/0000FFFF0002

[Queues]
exten => 7001,1,Verbose(2,${CALLERID(all)} entering the support queue)
        same => n,Queue(support)
        same => n,Hangup()
exten => 7002,1,Verbose(2,${CALLERID(all)} entering the sales queue)
        same => n,Queue(sales)
        same => n,Hangup()

[macro-automon]
exten => s,1,Set(MONITOR_FILENAME=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-${CALLERID(num)})
        same => n,Playback(beep) ; optional - hear when recording starts
        same => n,MixMonitor(${MONITOR_FILENAME}.wav,b)

[LocalSets]
include => Queues                              ; allow phones to call queues    
exten => 101,1,Dial(${EXT_TESTONE},20,m)       ; Replace 0000FFFF0001 with your device name
        same => n,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)     ; Play "no one's available"
        same => n,Hangup()

exten => 102,1,Noop(Dialing 102);
exten => 102,n,Macro(automon) ; start monitor
exten => 102,n,Dial(SIP/0000FFFF0002,30) ; 30 secs
exten => 102,n,Goto(s-${DIALSTATUS},1) ; Jump based on status (NOANSWER,BUSY,CHANUNAVAIL,CONGESTION,ANSWER)
exten => 102-NOANSWER,1,Voicemail(20,us) ; If unavailable, send to voicemail w/ unavail announce
exten => 102-NOANSWER,n,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => 102-NOANSWER,n,Hangup
exten => 102-BUSY,1,Voicemail(${MACRO_EXTEN},bs) ; If busy, send to voicemail w/ busy announce
exten => 102-BUSY,n,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => 102-BUSY,n,Hangup
exten => _102-.,1,Goto(s-NOANSWER,1) ; Treat anything else as no answer

;exten => 102,1,Dial(${EXT_TESTTWO},20,m)  ;Replace 0000FFFF0002 with your device name
        ;same => n,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)     ; Play "no one's available"
        ;same => n,Hangup()
```

The calling from 101 to 102 and 102 to 101 work fine. But there are no recordings which come under `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor`. Moreover, during the call, I get the following debug output:

```
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 was pretty quick last time, waiting for them.
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 and write factory 0x7f9710020068 both fail to provide 160 samples
No remote address on RTP instance '0x7f9710009258' so dropping frame
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 was pretty quick last time, waiting for them.
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 and write factory 0x7f9710020068 both fail to provide 160 samples
No remote address on RTP instance '0x7f9710009258' so dropping frame
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 was pretty quick last time, waiting for them.
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 and write factory 0x7f9710020068 both fail to provide 160 samples
No remote address on RTP instance '0x7f9710009258' so dropping frame
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 was pretty quick last time, waiting for them.
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 and write factory 0x7f9710020068 both fail to provide 160 samples
No remote address on RTP instance '0x7f9710009258' so dropping frame
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 was pretty quick last time, waiting for them.
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 and write factory 0x7f9710020068 both fail to provide 160 samples
No remote address on RTP instance '0x7f9710009258' so dropping frame
Read factory 0x7f971001f428 was pretty quick last time, waiting for them.
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I enable call recordings for both incoming and outgoing calls on a particular extension?

Comment: Merry Christmas. As trivial as this may sound, have you checked the destination's permissions?

Comment: @rahuL - Yes, that was the issue. I changed the permissions of `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor` to 777 and recordings started to appear. Could you add it in the answers section so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed the O'Reilly book as is, it asks you to create a user called `asteriskpbx` and run the rest of the configurations as that user. As a result, during the installation process in the beginning, the `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor` folder may have **write** permissions only for root. You need to give **write** permissions to for the user/ group which is actually writing into the folder (i.e writing the `.wav` file to that location).

`chmod -R 775 /var/spool/asterisk/monitor`

This should fix it for you. hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you using mixmonitor you have check that your sip devices have

```
directmedia=no
```

Also you can have more info by enabling debugging

Comment: what does this argument signify? could you explain a little bit please?

Comment: With directmedia=yes your rtp(sound) go outside asterisk.So it can't be recorded.